# CefSharp Winform MDI

Tags: c#, winforms, tinymce, cefsharp

I need a winforms control running TinyMCE js editor. I've successfully created a project with cefSharp 91.1.23, based on the minimal sample, SimpleBrowserForm. There's a control hosting a ChromiumWebBrowser pointing to an HTML page which then run the Tiny editor, I added it to a form and it display my editor fully functional.

Problem is the existing application that will use the control is an MDI winforms on .NET 4.5.2. When started from an MDI parent my form shows the editor with no focus, typing does not put text in the TinyMCE textarea, I've tried to switch to the more complex sample with multiThreadedMessageLoop enabled with no luck.

I also had problem with the missing CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll, I solved by copying it manually in the bin\x86\Debug directory

I uploaded a project on gitHub reproducing the problem, in case a good soul can point me to the solution ;)

here is the link to the repository, please note the tiny files and the HTML under bin\x86\Debug:
https://github.com/fabolo/WinFormCefSharpTest
a screenshot of the app:
https://github.com/fabolo/WinFormCefSharpTest/blob/main/screenshot.PNG

Comment: Are you giving the ChromiumWebBrowser focus with the mouse? Please reduce the example code to minimum required to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes, I'm clicking with the mouse and type with the keyboard, trying to select a menu from tiny, nothing happens, although tiny js code is running, I can configure various options etc. I've just downloaded my repository, selected x86 in the configuration and run in visual studio 2019, it reproduce the problem while being stripped to the minimum, maybe some handlers are redundant but that is not something I'm able to discern

Comment: The idea is to provide an example that has only the code required. Does the problem reproduce if you load Google?  If yes remove tiny mce from the project. A single project with just the the required classes would be preferable. Remove all the handlers, if the problem goes away then add then back one at a time until you identify which is required. Delete any code that's not required. Start from scratch if that's easier. Please make sure you've read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you @amaitland for your answer. I started from scratch, ignoring  even the example in CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms, I only added the control ChromiumWebBrowser via code to the control collection and called cefr.EnableHighDPISupport at startup and and it works, an MDI winforms application, just what I needed!

Comment: Great. Commit your code into your source repository often, then then you can run a git bisect if you experience the problem again, track down exactly which changes introduced the problem.